# I can't click on anything using selenium on a virtual machine web browser

Tags: python, selenium

[I'm kind of new using python/selenium]

I wrote a script where it extracts some data from a website, it was working just fine...! until recently the website migrated to an Amazon web server application. Now to access it I use a kind of web browser inside of web browser (like a virtual machine) and because of that I'm not able to click on anything with my script anymore.

I open the website with chrome web driver. and the virtual machine opens a firefox web browser inside the chromedriver.

I tried to switch to geckodriver.exe(firefox) but still can't click on anything.

I keep getting these errors:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element.

Comment: maybe Element which you are looking for is inside `iframe` check it.

Comment: In my original script the element is inside of an iframe but now when I use driver.switch_to.frame('iframe') I can't reach any iframe in the website anymore. Is it possible to click on anything in a virtual machine web browser?

Comment: first you need to get that iframe can you show us website or Html structure?

Comment: Thank you for your time Giorgi. I believe I did some research and came across this question https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27057/is-there-any-tool-to-automate-desktop-application-which-is-hosted-on-amazon-aws which is exactly what happend. Any solutions to that? besides recommending SikuliX